# J2ME/Blackberry - how to read/write text file?

Tags: blackberry, file-io, java-me, text-files, jsr75

please give me a sample code for read/write text file in blackberry application.

Answer (score 29):

My code snippet for string read/write files:

```
private String readTextFile(String fName) {
  String result = null;
  FileConnection fconn = null;
  DataInputStream is = null;
  try {
   fconn = (FileConnection) Connector.open(fName, Connector.READ_WRITE);
   is = fconn.openDataInputStream();
   byte[] data = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);
   result = new String(data);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  } finally {
   try {
    if (null != is)

     is.close();
    if (null != fconn)
     fconn.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   }
  }
  return result;
 }
```

---

```
private void writeTextFile(String fName, String text) {
  DataOutputStream os = null;
  FileConnection fconn = null;
  try {
   fconn = (FileConnection) Connector.open(fName, Connector.READ_WRITE);
   if (!fconn.exists())
    fconn.create();

   os = fconn.openDataOutputStream();
   os.write(text.getBytes());
  } catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  } finally {
   try {
    if (null != os)
     os.close();
    if (null != fconn)
     fconn.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: It's better to use Connector.READ_WRITE instead of Connector.WRITE (in my case the second does not work).

Answer (score 4):

Using

[FileConnection Interface](http://www.microemu.org/microemu-extensions/microemu-jsr-75/apidocs/javax/microedition/io/file/FileConnection.html)