# BlackBerry - Modify innnet text of node in xml file

Tags: xml, blackberry, java-me

I am working on blackberry java development. I am having a xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
    <url>www.test.com</url>
    <username>testuser</username>
    <password>sun123ARC</password>
    <width>350</width>
    <height>350</height>
</settings>
```

I want to change the inner text of all nodes. After saving when I open the xml file again, the saved data should open. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two options:

- use kxml (you will need to import 3dr party lib). See [Better approach for XML Creation in Blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877428/better-approach-for-xml-creation-in-blackberry)
- implement custom parser to search and replace text reading String from InputStream, and saving back to OutputStream. See [J2ME/Blackberry - how to read/write text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519328/j2me-blackberry-how-to-read-write-text-file) for file io sample and [StringMatch API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/util/StringMatch.html) for search implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what this is for in your question, but if your goal is to persist configuration data for your app, you may also want to look into using the [PersistentStore](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/PersistentStore.html) API instead of storing XML files to the filesystem.  No third-party libraries requires and it only takes a few lines of code.