# Save .JSON using Java ME

Tags: java, json, java-me

I have used toJSON() to convert java to json. How do I save that json data as a .json file?

I am using blackberry and Java me. Does anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't .json just an ordinary text-file containing your "json-ified" objects? What you need is an textfile where you write the output from the toJSON() method. How that is done is explained here:

[J2ME/Blackberry - how to read/write text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519328/j2me-blackberry-how-to-read-write-text-file)