# Using J2se for phone

Tags: java, java-me

I'm new to MIDlet. I'm trying to developpe a music player which accesses to files and folders. Seem j2me does'nt support file/folder management, can I use j2se (which has larger APIs lib) to developpe my program?
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't use lib from SE in ME, it is not how it is designed,

However [J2ME already supports](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/index-156490.html) [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519328/j2me-blackberry-how-to-read-write-text-file)